# Can I call sscanf mutliple times on the same string?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a line from a file, I grab a line `line` using `fgets`. I then try to use `sscanf` to parse it. Sometimes I'll call `sscanf` and find out it returns the wrong number of arguments. So then I'll try reparse the same `line` string. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (which is leading me to believe that the problem isn't `sscanf` but something else in my code). Here's an example of what I mean:

```
i = sscanf(line,"%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &faceV1, &faceUV1, &faceN1, &faceV2, &faceUV2, &faceN2, &faceV3, &faceUV3, &faceN3,
                &faceV4, &faceUV4, &faceN4);

if(i == 12) {
    //We gotta quad...
    printf("Model.c: Quads not supported\n");
} else if(sscanf(line,"%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &faceV1, &faceUV1, &faceN1, &faceV2, &faceUV2, &faceN2, &faceV3, &faceUV3, &faceN3) == 9) {
    //Doesn't do what I expect!
    ...
```

However if I get rid of `i = sscanf...` and the check for `i == 12` and go straight to `if(sscanf(line,"%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &faceV1, &faceUV1, &faceN1, &faceV2, &faceUV2, &faceN2, &faceV3, &faceUV3, &faceN3) == 9)` it will work as expected.

So back to the title of this question, can I call `sccanf` multiple times on the same string? Am I calling it wrong? Or should I look elsewhere in my code for the problem?

Comment: yes not problem, it override the value of string

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't do what I expect!"? What do you expect, and what does it do? And yes, you can call `sscanf` as often on the same string as you want.

Comment: The other commenters are right. Calling sscanf multiple times is no problem. But you can just call it once and check the value of i. sscanf will try to match as many conversions as possible before hitting a matching error. Also check i against EOF, which is returned in case the end of the string is reached without a match or a matching error. Read the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Comment: Your input string is the problem..., but anyway, in your example, why do you call sscanf twice?

Comment: @DanielFischer I expect it to put the first 9 values into faceV1 etc. The reason I called sscanf the second time is because the first time it doesn't do what I thought it would. If I get rid of the first sscanf and leave the second, it works like I want it to. If I keep the first sscanf in and either call sscanf again or use the original one and check for i == 9, it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: What _does_ it do, and for what string?

Comment: Eh, clearly I am confused. I was wrong when I said calling sscanf the second time doesn't work. Anyways what I'm trying to do is load in a model, and when I call that sscanf then i should == 12, if it doesn't and then I check if i == 9, my following code doesn't work. However if I do the second sscanf == 9, it will load it in properly. So clearly this must be a problem with what my code does. Does it look like I'm calling sscanf wrong in any way? (I've got rid of the /n btw.) My two sscanf's should put the same values into faceV1 etc even if it only does the first 9 instead of 12, right?

Comment: Hmm, I think I have an idea as to what's going wrong. Will sscanf ever return 12 for my first one if it only found 9?

Comment: Ugh, nvm I have found out what was wrong and it was really stupid on my part. I had previously been loading in quads as the first 3 vertices and I was thinking that viewing that was a good way to judge if the model had been loaded in properly. When I switched to the i == 12 to say that quads aren't supported, I was losing all those half quad triangles that I was foolishly thinking were part of the model. Clearly I need to learn how to debug better and not rely on visuals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer YES you can sscanf the same string multiple times.

Your problem is that having "\n" in your string does not do what you expect... 
It matches ANY white-space character space, tab, \r, and not just \n.

So you need to check for the end-of-line after scanf'ing.